# Is there a street or neighborhood in Puerto Plata, DR featuring a high concentration of shops & resturants?

Tags: shopping, dominican-republic

I'm taking a trip to Puerto Plata in the Dominican Republic soon.

I'm wondering if there's a "walkable" street or neighborhood that has a lot of small shops & restaurants. I'm hoping to find a place like 5th Avenue / Avenida 5 in Playa Del Carmen. That is, a street with a lot of small businesses close enough to each other to see a lot of different places without needing a vehicle to get around the neighborhood.

So far I've tried Google, and browsing around Google maps looking for a high concentration of location markers but would up with nothing.

Comment: Why do you care? Are you looking for the best place to get accommodation?

Comment: @JonathanReez I thought this would be implied by my having asked the question, but I am interested in shopping and eating food while on vacation.

Answer (score 2):

Google has [implemented this very feature](https://blog.google/products/maps/discover-action-around-you-with-updated/) last year on their Maps: zooming in on any city you can see which areas are the most popular (they're highlighted brown). Specifically for Puerto Plata the answer is that the hotspot of activity is around **Estacion Metro**. There are also several popular restaurants visible in that area on the map.

[image]